Are questions specific to a potential BTU hard fork on topic?
There have been a lot of recent questions about a BTU hard fork, but many of them are really just about hard forks in general.  Should we encourage users to generalize these questions?

At the moment, I'd say that BTU is a central topic in the Bitcoin community, and especially due to much information/discussion about it being only available on Reddit, Twitter or private forums, not one easy to research.
I assume that quite a few people land here when researching Bitcoin Unlimited, and it's beneficial to have some of the information easily findable.
So, for the above reasons, and since we also cover altcoins here anyway, I'd leave it be at the moment. We can reconsider merging the Bitcoin Unlimited tag into hardfork if/when the topic cools down.
